# Function pointer inside a constant struct

Tags: c

I'm using a driver written by someone else.
To access the driver functions, I have to use a function access struct like the one below: (defined in a header file, say, **driver.h**)

```
typedef struct _driver {
  void (*init) (void);           // init is supposed to point to _init
} const driver;                  // problem here with **const**

----------------------------------------------------------------------

void _init (void) {              // defined in another file, say, driver.c
  // init code 
}
```

How can I make **init** point to **_init** ?

The following code works if the driver is not **const**:

```
driver dr;
dr.init = &_init;                // modifying directly 
((driver*)(&dr))->init = &_init; // modifying through a pointer
```

According to the documentation, the driver is supposed to be used as follows:

```
driver dr;
driver *pdr = &dr;
pdr->init();
```

In order for this code to work, **dr.init** must point **_init**, but I can't find it anywhere in the code. 
Any input is greatly appreciated.

Best regards,

Sergey

Answer (score 0):

Use an *initializer*, e.g.

```
driver dr = { _init };
```

Answer (score 0):

rmartinjak's answer is right, but if you have gcc extensions enabled or using C99 and above, you can [use designated initializers](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Designated-Inits.html). Since your driver struct will probably have more members, this way will probably end up being cleaner looking.

```
driver dr = {
    .init = _init,
    /* .member = value, */
};
```

Comment: _Designated initializers_ is standard C and not just a GCC extension.

Comment: To be exact: since C99.